# Check Range from table where arithmetic operators are also in the same table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How will I get col5 value from table named table for an integer input

`col3` is related to `col1` and `col4` related to `col2`.

```
col1   col2     col3    col4     col5
75       0       <               Approved
50      70       >       <       Conditionally Approved
20      50       >       <       Rejected
```

If I give 74 as input, my expected output is `col5` value (`'approved'`).

Comment: For input `15 - Approved` and `55 - Conditionally Approved`, `31 - Rejected`, is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the following query should do the trick:

```
SELECT col5
FROM mytable
WHERE    
    ( 
        col3 IS NULL 
        OR (col3 = '<' AND @input < col1) 
        OR (col3 = '>' AND @input > col1) 
    ) AND ( 
        col4 IS NULL 
        OR (col4 = '<' AND @input < col2) 
        OR (col4 = '>' AND @input > col2) 
    )
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=964c0512919ec2556f47628a43401ec3)** with your sample data:

DECLARE @input INTEGER;
    SET @input = 74;

```
SELECT col5
FROM mytable
WHERE    
    ( 
        col3 IS NULL 
        OR (col3 = '<' AND @input < col1) 
        OR (col3 = '>' AND @input > col1) 
    ) AND ( 
        col4 IS NULL 
        OR (col4 = '<' AND @input < col2) 
        OR (col4 = '>' AND @input > col2) 
    )


GO
```

```
| col5     |
| :------- |
| Approved |
```

NB: there are discrepencies in your intervals. FOr example, a value between 20 and 50 would typically match on two records (0-75 and 20-50).

Answer (score 0):

If the question is really how to calculate `col5` then the following code is applicable:

```
declare @Value as Int = 74;

select col1, col2, col3, col4,
  case
    when col3 = '<' and @Value < col1 and col4 = '' then 'Approved'
    when col3 = '>' and @Value > col1 and col4 = '<' and @Value < col2 then 'Conditionally Approved'
    else 'Rejected' end as col5
  from mytable;
```

Note that it is assumed that the sample data covers all cases and that any approval failure results in "Rejected". Additional `when` clauses can be added to handle additional comparisons and status returns.